# How to measure the similarity of a matrix to triangular form

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix A, how to measure its similarity (row and column permutations can be performed on A) to triangular form, here the triangular form is like
\begin{align}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
       0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
This triangular form is different from upper triangular matrix. Besides requiring all the entries below the main diagonal are zero, I'd like the entries above the main diagonal are 1 as much as possible.

For example, the similarity between A,B,C and M should satisfy
$sim(A,M)>sim(B,M)>sim(C,M)$

A has the highest similarity, which is actually same as M after swapping column 1 and 4.

\begin{align}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
       1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}
&
B = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
&
C = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: What about some norm of $X-M$, where $X=A,B,C$?

Answer (score 0):

If all elements of $A$ are supposed to be $0$ or $1$, then we can use an idea of [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). For this purpose let $\sigma(A)$ be the set of all matrices, which can be obtained from the matrix $A$ by row and column permutations. For each matrix $A’\in \sigma(A)$ let $d’(A’,M)$ be the number of cells of matrices $A’$ and $M$ at which the corresponding numbers are different. Finally, put $$d(A,M)=\min\{ d’(A’,M): A’\in \sigma(A) \}.$$